# Parsing XML into Tilemap

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to parse an XML file using Java DOM into an int[][], but I can't figure out how to do it, and it keeps giving me strange results.

Here is the XML doc:

```
<layers>
<name>Untitled Layer</name>
<rows>
  <cells>
    <tileCode>1</tileCode>
  </cells>
  <cells>
    <tileCode>2</tileCode>
  </cells>
</rows>
<rows>
  <cells>
    <tileCode>-1</tileCode>
  </cells>
  <cells>
    <tileCode>4</tileCode>
  </cells>
</rows>
</layers>
```

I would like to get from this:
[1, 2]
[-1, 4]

```
NodeList rowList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rows");

                  map = new int[rowList.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength()][rowList.getLength()];

                  for (int y = 0; y < rowList.getLength(); ++y){
                      NodeList cellList = rowList.item(y).getChildNodes();
                      for (int x = 0; x < cellList.getLength(); ++x){
                          Node cell = cellList.item(x);

                          if (cell.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                          map[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(((Element) cell).getElementsByTagName("tileCode").item(0).getTextContent());
                          }
                      }
                  }

                  System.out.println("Tilesize: " + tileSize + ", numTilesAccresos: " + getNumTilesAcross() + ", tilesDown: " + tilesDown + ", tilesetFile: " + tileset_file + " W: " + map[0].length);
                  for(int y = 0; y < map[0].length; ++y){
                      for(int x = 0; x < map.length; ++x){
                          System.out.print(map[x][y] + ",");
                      }
                      System.out.println("");
                  }
```

But this returns: [0,1,0,2,0]
[0,-1,0,4,0]?

Comment: can u do the same using ArrayList<Integer> instead of int[][] and den adding to it?? it will give you the  output  wanted

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("D:/StackOverFlow/DOMTester/src/you.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList rowList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rows");
            int[][] map = new int[rowList.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength()-3][rowList.getLength()];
            for (int y = 0; y < rowList.getLength(); ++y) {
                NodeList cellList = rowList.item(y).getChildNodes();
                int k=0;
                for (int x = 0; x < cellList.getLength(); ++x) {
                    Node cell = cellList.item(x);
                                    if (cell.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        if((Integer.parseInt(((Element) cell).getElementsByTagName("tileCode").item(0).getTextContent()))!=0){

                        map[k][y] = Integer.parseInt(((Element) cell)
                                .getElementsByTagName("tileCode").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                        k++;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            for (int y = 0; y < map[0].length; ++y) {
                for (int x = 0; x < map.length; ++x) {
                    System.out.print(map[x][y] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

out put

1 2

-1 4